# Firestore limitations with active valueChanges listeners

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a firebase web app where the user logs in and sees a sort of "dashboard" with data from Firestore. Changes to the data are synced to the app via valueChanges. The PC is then connected to a large TV in an office for people to see the dashboard as they pass by. Two questions:

- Will firestore limit the number of users that have listening to valueChanges at the same time (effectively limiting how many users I can have doing it this way)?
- Can the connection to valueChanges stop at some point? I.E if no new data comes in for a while? Or after a certain delay regardless of data coming in? Will the user ever need to interact with the page / refresh to prevent the listener from dying?

Thanks

Tried with a few listeners active for 3-4 days of no user interaction and so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

- Firebase RTDB (Realtime Database) One instance/bucket can be easily "listen" by 200k people at the same time.
- Firebase Firestore can hold easily 1 million people at the same time.

The limits above are soft limits, for example, Firebase Firestore might be working well even with 10 million users listening to the database at the same time.

Firebase RTDB same as Firebase Firestore has an option in the web app to `enableIndexedDBPersistance()` this helps with working offline on the app. For example, if the computer doesn't shoot down but only loses an internet connection, the app will back up to fresh data by itself. This future has more benefits, for example, if you are offline and want to save something to a database your computer will register it and do it after you reconnect to the internet. While no connection you can save data close the browser and later when you back open the app in the browser, the app will send data to a server if the connection is back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond. For the second point in my question - can there be a case where the valueChanges subscription will stop by itself (i.e after a long time etc) even though the browser has internet connection etc? My concern is if this PC is left connected to a screen for a long time with no user interaction, the valueChanges will at some point stop working due to it being on for too long, or no new data was received for too long etc.

Comment: @ep_mxl Yeah, when your browser stops working. Add a clock to your page, you should realize faster if your browser stops working. Listeners in a Firebase have no any time limits. They will work as long as browser/application/system can handle.

Comment: Perfect thanks, that's what I was looking for - the no time limits inherent to Firebase for listeners. Is this documented anywhere?